# How to prepend html text for a selected element in ckeditor 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, comments

I am using CKEditor 4.3.3, Where i have added table .Now table structure looks like given below

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now i am able to select table using javascript as

```
CKEDITOR.instances.ficeditor.getSelection().getStartElement().getParent().getParent();
```

Now i want to add html text before `<tbody>` start and after `<table>` start .

```
CKEDITOR.instances.ficeditor.getSelection().getStartElement().getParent().getParent().appendHtml("<!-- <div>" +html+"</div> -->");
```

I am using this to append HTML. But for prepending HTML i am not able to find any API

Is there any alternatives?

```
I want output to be like this
    <table>
<!-- <div>testing</div> -->
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: What is the purpose to get code like that? Most likely you will run into problems with trying to include HTML comments inside CKEditor and secondly I don't think that nesting a div inside a table like that is possible. To add metadata, how about using custom attributes on the table itself?

Comment: My intention is to use server side scripting in side comment and will remove comment while processing

Comment: Just as I thought. This can be achieved easier using attributes or other kinds of embedded data, there will be much less problems later with things like it. The only reason why attributes might not work is if you want a LOT of data, but if that's the case I'm sure that there is a logic solution available, something other than this. This does not seem like a good way to pass data, think about your requirements and try to change the data exchange format and such, I'm sure you will find a better way!

Answer (score 0):

you can use any jquery functions by

```
var html=CKEDITOR.instances.ficeditor.getSelection().getStartElement().getParent().getParent().getParent();
    $(html.$).prepend("hi");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
    var editor  = CKEDITOR.instances.ficeditor;
    var data = $("<div>"+editor.getData()+"</div>");
    data.prepend("top line");
    editor.setData(data.html());
```